# Create a custom CRS of the Moon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, moon

I am trying to create a custom CRS of the Moon. I am currently using GCS_Moon_2000 which is great, but for my work I require the projection to be Mercator, not Equidistant Area. I have found a custom CRS on spatialreference.org site for this, however I need to use Lat/Long, not meters. I have played around with creating a custom CRS in Settings but have so far not been successful. Specifically I’m having issues with what I should be inputting into parameters. I think I should be setting +proj=merc and +datum=D_Moon_2000, is there anything else I need?

Comment: You *can't* have a Mercator projected coordinte system with angular units. You can play with the  Cartesian units (meters, feet, furlongs,..), but you can't substitute angular units (even though the Cartesian units are useless for measurement in Mercator). This appears to be an XY Problem. Please [Edit] the Question to explain **why** you want those units.

Comment: @Vince thank you for the simple explanation, seems I need to study GIS 101. The data I’m using is SLDEM2015 and the actual issue I’m trying to resolve is the warping the closer I move to the poles. It seems this might be a data issue though, I’ll check for data that better represents the areas I’m studying. 

Thank you